# Is there a way to select an open select box in css?

Tags: html, css, select, selector, html-select

I set a background image (arrow down) to a select box after setting the webkit-appearance attribute to none. When the option list is opened I want to display another background image (arrow up). Is there a pseudo class or something for it? I couldn't find anything during my research...

Comment: Hi, please show us any of the code that you have attempted, then we can start helping you in the right direction

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not possible to detect if a HTML `select` element is opened using CSS, or even javascript.

If you wish to customise the arrow symbol of a custom dropdown, your best option is to use a custom dropdown component which maps to a hidden `select` element.

Comment: oh what a shame, such a function would be useful. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 26):

you can use the [`:focus`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) pseudo class.

But this will indicate the "open" state, also when the `<select>` is selected via tab or an item was just selected. To circumvent this, you maybe use something like `select:hover:focus` but this is rather ugly and is not a solid solution.

```css
select:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Click me</option>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: select:focus:active does the job at least in Chrome.

Comment: better than nothing, at least in Chrome, but the problem is that selecting an option still stays in a state of open untill you move the mouse of the element

Comment: select:focus:active also doesn't work in Chrome if the control is opened by the keyboard.

Answer (score 10):

This post is old, but as today; the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-class still don't work on select element.

Here's a good opportunity to use the `:focus-within` pseudo-class. I made this simple codepen demonstrating the use of it.

The [codepen](https://codepen.io/C0rdyc3p5/pen/PojEdbJ)

The snippet :

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 22px;
  font-size: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.wrapper:focus-within::after {
  transform: rotateX(0.5turn) translateY(-2px);
}
.wrapper select {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #F8F9FB 0%, #F1F2F4 100%);
  border: 1px solid var(--grayscale-400);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  appearance: none;
}
.wrapper select:focus {
  outline: unset;
}
.wrapper select > option:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option>Choice Label First</option>
    <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="Choice 3">Choice 3</option>
    <option value="Choice 4">Choice 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: sadly, it doesn't work as intended, with similar problems as `:focus` itself

Comment: I tried using just `:focus-within` and it worked